# tick checkbox and insert value in textbox for calculation in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i need to count about the number to the tree had been plant and the plant can release how much CO2. So, i need to multiply the number of tree and the function of the planttree.  how to `multiply` the number to plant with the function of plant tree after i click the `checkbox of the planttree and insert the total number of plant`.

> for example, if i insert 2 plant, it must be 2*-(22/12)= -3.67

```js
var person = [];
person["person1"] = 1;
person["person2"] = 2;
person["person3"] = 3;
person["person4"] = 4;
person["person5"] = 5;

var elec = [];
elec["elecuse"] = 0;
elec["elec1"] = 100 * (5455 / 12);
elec["elec2"] = 150 * (5455 / 12);
elec["elec3"] = 200 * (5455 / 12);
elec["elec4"] = 250 * (5455 / 12);
elec["elec5"] = 300 * (5455 / 12);

function getNumberperson() {
  var numberperson = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["energyform"];
  var selectedPerson = theForm.elements["selectedperson"];
  for (var i = 0; i < selectedPerson.length; i++) {
    if (selectedPerson[i].checked) {
      numberperson = person[selectedPerson[i].value];
    }
  }
  return numberperson;
}

function getElectotal() {
  var electotal = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["energyform"];
  var selectedElec = theForm.elements["electricity"];
  electotal = elec[selectedElec.value];
  return electotal;
}

function planttree() {
  var planttree = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["energyform"];
  var plant = theForm.elements["plant"];

  if (plant.checked == true) {
    planttree = -(22 / 12);
  }
  return planttree;
}

function calculateTotal() {
  var HMontotalco = getNumberperson() * getElectotal() + planttree();
  var hmco = document.getElementById('totalHMonthCst').innerHTML = "Per Month = " + HMontotalco.toFixed(2) + " pounds";
}
```

```html
<body onload='hideTotal()'>
  <div id="all">
    <form action="/action_page.php" id="energyform" onsubmit="return false;">
      <div>
        <div class="cont_order">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Carbon Footprint Calculator</legend>
            <label>Number of Person Live in Household</label><br/>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedperson" value="person1" onclick="calculateTotal()">1&nbsp</label>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedperson" value="person2" onclick="calculateTotal()">2&nbsp</label>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedperson" value="person3" onclick="calculateTotal()">3&nbsp</label>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedperson" value="person4" onclick="calculateTotal()">4&nbsp</label>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedperson" value="person5" onclick="calculateTotal()">5&nbsp</label>
            <br/>
            <label>&nbspElectricity&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</label>
            <select id="electricity" name='electricity' onchange="calculateTotal();allvalidate()">
              <option value="elecuse">0kWh</option>
              <option value="elec1">100kWh</option>
              <option value="elec2">150kWh</option>
              <option value="elec3">200kWh</option>
              <option value="elec4">250kWh</option>
              <option value="elec5">300kWh</option>
            </select>
            <br/>
            <label for='plant' class="tree">Plant</label></hr>
            <input type="checkbox" id="plant" name='plant' onchange="calculateTotal();allvalidate()">
            <input type="text" id="textbox" name="textbox" value="Enter total plant" />
            <br/>
            <hr><label>Total CO2 produced per household</label></hr>
            <br/>
            <div id="totalHMonthCst">Per month = 0</div>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `.getElementById()` method instead of using `theForm.elements[]`.
You just have to get the value of `input` with id `textbox`. And multiply it. If you want to change the value as per the user **input** you can attach eventlistener `oninput` on that textbox.

```js
var person = [];
person["person1"] = 1;
person["person2"] = 2;
person["person3"] = 3;
person["person4"] = 4;
person["person5"] = 5;

var elec = [];
elec["elecuse"] = 0;
elec["elec1"] = 100 * (5455 / 12);
elec["elec2"] = 150 * (5455 / 12);
elec["elec3"] = 200 * (5455 / 12);
elec["elec4"] = 250 * (5455 / 12);
elec["elec5"] = 300 * (5455 / 12);

function getNumberperson() {
  var numberperson = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["energyform"];
  var selectedPerson = theForm.elements["selectedperson"];
  for (var i = 0; i < selectedPerson.length; i++) {
    if (selectedPerson[i].checked) {
      numberperson = person[selectedPerson[i].value];
    }
  }
  return numberperson;
}

function getElectotal() {
  var electotal = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["energyform"];
  var selectedElec = theForm.elements["electricity"];
  electotal = elec[selectedElec.value];
  return electotal;
}

function planttree() {
  var planttree = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["energyform"];
  var plant = theForm.elements["plant"];
  var txtBoxVal = document.getElementById("textbox").value;

  if (plant.checked === true) {
    planttree = txtBoxVal*(-(22 / 12));
  }
  return planttree;
}

function calculateTotal() {
  var HMontotalco = getNumberperson() * getElectotal() + planttree();
  var hmco = document.getElementById('totalHMonthCst').innerHTML = "Per Month = " + HMontotalco.toFixed(2) + " pounds";
}
```

```html
<body onload='hideTotal()'>
  <div id="all">
    <form action="/action_page.php" id="energyform" onsubmit="return false;">
      <div>
        <div class="cont_order">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Carbon Footprint Calculator</legend>
            <label>Number of Person Live in Household</label><br/>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedperson" value="person1" onclick="calculateTotal()">1&nbsp</label>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedperson" value="person2" onclick="calculateTotal()">2&nbsp</label>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedperson" value="person3" onclick="calculateTotal()">3&nbsp</label>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedperson" value="person4" onclick="calculateTotal()">4&nbsp</label>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedperson" value="person5" onclick="calculateTotal()">5&nbsp</label>
            <br/>
            <label>&nbspElectricity&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</label>
            <select id="electricity" name='electricity' onchange="calculateTotal();allvalidate()">
              <option value="elecuse">0kWh</option>
              <option value="elec1">100kWh</option>
              <option value="elec2">150kWh</option>
              <option value="elec3">200kWh</option>
              <option value="elec4">250kWh</option>
              <option value="elec5">300kWh</option>
            </select>
            <br/>
            <label for='plant' class="tree">Plant</label></hr>
            <input type="checkbox" id="plant" name='plant' onchange="calculateTotal();allvalidate()">
            <input type="text" oninput="calculateTotal();" id="textbox" name="textbox" placeholder="Enter total plant" />
            <br/>
            <hr><label>Total CO2 produced per household</label></hr>
            <br/>
            <div id="totalHMonthCst">Per month = 0</div>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```